# Dealing with portrait and landscape images in Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am working on a news app, and I would like to present portrait and landscape images in the news details page using Xamarin forms.

I would like to have full width image based on screen orientation and the height will be calculated based on image width saving the aspect ratio (without cropping the image). [see attached images]

What is the best practice to do that in Xamarin Forms?

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no easy solution to this because the control doesn't automatically scale. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41395453/4825351

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually - you know your image sizes, also you know your phone width, so getting height is not a problem. After that just set `yourimage.HeightRequest = yourheight`, nad that's all.