# Full Width Image in Modal Clipped by Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, xml, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a full-width image inside a modal, but the image is going behind the navigation bar on some iOS devices.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.ModalWithFullWidthImage" 
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" >
            <Image Source="fullWithImage" Aspect="AspectFill" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

The problem is on iPhone 11: the navigation bar blocks the top of the image. The image appears as if it is behind the navigation bar. On iPhone 8, the image is fine.

I need the image to maintain its aspect but go edge-to-edge on the width. The height can be variable and can be cutoff on smaller devices.

I am hoping to find a solution that just uses Xaml. I have seen solutions that adjust the image in the codebehind, but I have to believe there is a simpler solution or workaround.

Comment: "BackgroundImageSource" did you try with this in the content page

Comment: Hi, No, I haven't tried that. How would that work? Does the background only apply to the entire page or can I assign it to a grid or stacklayout content area too? How do I know the height if it is variable?

Comment: `<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MyApp.ModalWithFullWidthImage" 
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
BackgroundImageSource="myImage.png">`

it is something like this

Comment: That doesn't seem to work because it tiles (repeats) the image and also requires a custom renderer for scaling the image to the various devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` with `FillAndExpand`:

```
<StackLayout>
    <!-- Place new controls here -->
    <Image Source="Images" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
   VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Refer: [Image with AspectFill](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/11149) and [xamarin-forms-image-fill-width-with-proper-aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395248/xamarin-forms-image-fill-width-with-proper-aspect)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use `On<iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);` on the ContentPage? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/ios/page-safe-area-layout

Comment: I did just try that now, and iPhone 11 still covers the top.